# Page jumping when filling form in iframe on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, scroll

I have a problem with iOS browsers

**This is starter conditions:**
    - We have a simple html page and it contains iframe
    - iframe also contains simple html page with form
    - iframe haven't scroll and it sizes is fixed

**Bug:**
    Now, if we will open this page on iPhone(from Chrome/Safari browser) and start fill form,
    then in some moment when text printing, page scroll down by itself

[This is example link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrGmXb)

```
<div id="container">

  <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/php/demo_form_validation_complete.php" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

Why is this happening? How to prevent these automatic "jumps" of the page?

Comment: so ... what is it that you want to know here? What is your question? Is it :
why is your page scrolling automatically in the browser or what ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I edited the post and clarified the question

Comment: thanks for doing that.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue... Thanks

Comment: any fix for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scroll-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    /* important:  dimensions or positioning here! */
}

.scroll-wrapper iframe {
    /* nada! */
}
```

Source: https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios